# How to get the previous version of a file from S3 without pagination

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, version

I want to compare the latest version of a S3 document with the previous version.
If the latest revision is 10, I want to compare against 9.

The list-object-versions S3 call returns a paginated list of ALL revisions starting from the very first revision. If a file has been modified many times, I would have to paginate all the way until the end to find the previous file edit. I do not see any way to reverse the sort order of this call.

Is there a way for me get the latest-1 revision without paginating?

Comment: There's no way to do this with the API afaik. If it's really important, or you're doing this frequently, then you might want to store the VersionIdMarker of the penultimate version, and ideally maintain that automatically via Lambda or some other solution.

Comment: If you are using the aws cli you can limit the pagination by supplying --no-paginate. The cli returns the versions in descending order so revision 9 in your example would be the second item in the list.